# Firestore Admin Create an anonymous user

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Trying to create an anonymous user using admin (i use cloud functions) but i have no idea if it possible or not:

```
admin.auth().createUser({
  email: userEmail,
  emailVerified: false,
  password: userPassword,
  disabled: false, 
  anonymous: true
})
.then(function(userRecord) {
    console.log("util = " + util.inspect(userRecord))
    console.log("user recotd = " + userRecord.anonymous)
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error creating new user:", error);
});
```

On the documentation in the admin section there is no "Anonymous user" part.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/

Any idea if it possible or not ?

Thanks !

Comment: Answer below. But I'm having a hard time thinking of a use-case here, so it feels like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish by creating a specifically *anonymous* user account?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hey Puf, I found this thread which servers my user case. In my particular case I want to invite users but inmediately modify their profile, add trips (this is a travel agency app) and if I create a user on the spot, I know the UID in advance, which allows me to do simpler security rules. Once the user finally signup, I copy the data over. Otherwise I need to defer any work on the user profile until they actually signup which is bad UX.

Answer (score 4):

To create an **anonymous** Firebase user account using the Firebase Admin SDK, be sure that the `Anonymous` sign-in provider is enabled in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) `> Your Project > Authentication > Sign-in method`

[image: Firebase Console Sign-in method]

In your code, after you have [initialized the SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup/#initialize_the_sdk), call [createUser(properties: CreateRequest): Promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#createuser) with no arguments.

```
admin.auth().createUser({})
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    console.log('Successfully created new anonymous user:', userRecord.uid);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error creating new anonymous user:', error);
  });
```

If you check the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) `> Your Project > Authentication > Users`, the new Anonymous user will be listed.

[image: Firebase Anonymous User]

Comment: This no longer seems to be the case. `admin.auth().createUser({})` now creates user with _empty_ (you can see just `-` in  Firebase console) provider, not anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a user through the Firebase Admin SDK it is just a Firebase Authentication user profile. It is not tied to any specific provider.

There is no way to specifically create an anonymous user account through the Firebase Admin SDK.

Comment: yes you can, you simply add disabled: false, and no other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an anonymous user using the admin SDK,

Simply create a key for firebase service-account in GCP and initalize the app with that key.

```
admin.auth().createUser({})
```

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/keys-create-delete