# how to create anonymous account programmatically using Admin SDK that signed in at certain time?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

hi I need to perform testing for my cloud function, but I need to create dummy anonymous account in Authentication emulator

I need to create anonymous account that has last signed in data 2 months ago. how to do that?

to create account using email, I can use code like this

```
admin.auth().createUser({
    email: "jdoe@gmail.com",
    emailVerified: false,
    password: "secretPassword",
    displayName: "John Doe",
    disabled: false
});
```

how to create anonymous account programmatically using Admin SDK that signed in at certain time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore Admin Create an anonymous user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51361953/firestore-admin-create-an-anonymous-user)

Comment: @Dharmaraj I don't think that was the question. The question was how to create that account *that has last signed in data 2 months ago*. I think the OP knows how to create the account, just needs to know how to make a 'fake' login date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to set the creation data and time in the new account. As far as I can determine those values are managed by automatically when an ID token is generated when a user signs in to a (new or existimg) account from the client.

Comment: yup, even we can't update that metadata, there is no API to update the metadata https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user